# Conservative Quantum Logic Gate

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

In "Quantum Computation and Quantum Information," by Nielsen & Chuang, pg 156, a conservative logic gate is defined as one which preserves the number of zeros and ones. This definition makes sense for bits with definite 1's and 0's, but **how does this definition extend to qubits?**

For instance, consider the unitary operator $$ U = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2^{-1/2} & 2^{-1/2} & 0 \\
0 & 2^{-1/2} & 2^{-1/2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$
This gate takes a state $|01\rangle$ to a balanced superposition of $|01\rangle$ and $|10\rangle$, has it "conserved the number of 0's and 1's? (I think so.)

What about a gate that takes $|0011\rangle$ to a balanced superposition of $|0111\rangle$ and $|0001\rangle$?

EDIT: The question is really in the last line. Is a balanced superposition of $|0111\rangle$ and $|0001\rangle$ really "conserving" the number of 1's from $|0011\rangle$. While it commutes with the counting operator, measurement will definitely give a different number of 1's! So is that still called conservation?

Comment: I suppose it could mean any operator which commutes with the operator that counts the number of ones. In which case the answers to your questions are yes and yes.

Comment: That's one possibility, but what if the condition is that the operation must be guaranteed to preserve the count for any pure state, not just the expectation?

Comment: They may be describing gates whose matrix form is a permutation matrix (e.g. Toffoli, Fredkin, CNOT) - these gates have the property of jostling around 1's and 0's for a given input state. This is my best guess as to what N&C meant, especially since they were vague in defining what was being conserved: is there conservation of pre-measurement expectation values, or post-measurement properties?  In the first case, your matrix would satisfy "conservative", but in the second case it would not.

Comment: kzhou is right: The proper definition is to commute with the "number operator" counting the number of ones.  What other *linear* definition should there be?  ---  In any case, what precisely is the question here?

Comment: Grateful for input. I am asking if there might be a better non-linear definition or there is a good explanation why the second case is conservative even though it clearly does not preserve the number of 0's and 1's.

Comment: You haven't even DEFINED the second gate.  Just its action on ONE SPECIFIC STATE.  ---  BTW, you need to use @[username] to notify others of your comments.

Comment: No gate defined because I could not find such a gate. From Emilio's answer, apparently no such gate could exist. -- @NorbertSchuch, will do in the future.

Comment: Of course there exists such a gate!  It's just not clear what it does to other states, and so it's not clear if -- in any, even unreasonable, way -- it preserved some expectation value.  But given a vector $v$ and a vector $w$, there is always a gate which maps $v$ to $w$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The number of zeros" and "the number of ones" are, respectively, the matrices
$$
N_0=\begin{pmatrix}2&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}
\quad\text{and}\quad 
N_1=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&2 \end{pmatrix},
$$
in the $\{|00\rangle, |01\rangle, |10\rangle, |11\rangle \}$ basis, and they add to a multiple of the identity, $N_0+N_1=2=2\,\mathbb I$. Saying that a unitary $U$ "conserves the number of zeros" (or equivalently the number of ones) is, by definition, saying that it commutes with $N_0$ (and equivalently with $N_1$), and therefore that it takes any eigenvector of $N_0$ and $N_1$ (itself necessarily of the form $|00\rangle$, $a|01\rangle+b|10\rangle$, or $|11\rangle$) to another eigenvector of the same eigenvalue. The same is true, with a transparent generalization, to the tensor product of any number of qubits.

As such, if a unitary takes $|0011\rangle$ to a superposition of $|0111\rangle$ and $|0001\rangle$ then, regardless of how even-weighted the superposition, is **not** considered to conserve $N_1$, because it takes vectors from one eigenspace and puts them outside that eigenspace, and therefore it cannot commute with $N_1$.